# How to generate kernel dump by using Windbg?

Tags: kernel, windbg, crash-dumps

How to generate kernel dump by using WinDBG?

If I'm using the command, can it generate the Kernel dump?

```
.dump /f
```

or I have to use `.crash` to get the kernel dump?

Comment: If you're debugging the kernel, yes [`.dump`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff562428%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) can write a dump file to disk without a bugcheck. There are more details on the subject [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff540128%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Also, if you don't need a live debugging session, you can always use [livekd](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897415.aspx)'s `-o` switch to write a dump to disk.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, `.dump /f` generates a kernel dump when you're in kernel debugging mode. It'll not create a kernel dump when you're debugging in user mode.

`.crash` however, will crash the system, i.e. cause a BSOD (blue screen of death), which is not guaranteed to generate a kernel dump, especially not a full memory kernel dump. There are certain conditions for `.crash` to work:

1. BSOD crash dumps must be configured, especially if you want full RAM
2. The system must have a page file
3. The page file must be large enough to keep all RAM + a bit of overhead
4. The page file must be on the system partiion
5. There must be enough free disk space to copy the dump from the page file to disk during next startup

A similar effect can be achieved by [SysInternals NotMyFault](http://download.sysinternals.com/files/NotMyFault.zip) `/crash`, but it suffers under the same conditions.

So, the more reliable way is `.dump`.

As mentioned by Sean Cline before, you can use [SysInternals LiveKD](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897415.aspx) with the `-o` and perhaps `-m` switch to generate a kernel dump.

There are [other options](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/972110) as well, but I never successfully applied them myself, e.g. I never managed to take a kernel dump via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Scroll</kbd>+<kbd>Scroll</kbd>.

Comment: .dump also has the advantage of working very early in the boot cycle. The paging file has to actually be created for .crash to work, which doesn't happen until the user mode components start. The only downside is the .dump can be painfully slow. Best to do it over a 1394b connection.